# Bidirectional Replication SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication, bidirectional

I am trying to do Bidirectional transactional replication on SQL server. One way replication is working fine. e.g. From Server A to Server B but not the other way around. When doing from Server B to Server A the publication is sometime uninitialized or throw error.

Any tutorial or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Ensure both servers have the same publication, and @loopback_detection is set to true.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/bidirectional-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ok will give that a try and would let you know

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2019 DataCenter Evaluation Edition, I created the Publisher in Server A and Subscribed it in B. I created a Publisher in Server B with same database and contents and Subscribed it in A.

I granted access to the SQL Agent Account of A in Server B and SQL Agent Account of B in Server A.

I granted full access to the
E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.DEMOA\MSSQL\repldata  (Server A)
E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.DEMOB\MSSQL\repldata  (Server B)

and it worked perfectly for me.